# Cannot get jQuery click handler to fire on ajax loaded element

Tags: javascript, jquery

"MyParentPage.htm" uses the load function of jquery to load('myDiv.htm') //

myDiv.htm only contains:

```
<a href="#" class="bt-cbox">Click me</a>
```

I have the following in "MyParentPage.htm"

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(".bt-cbox").click(function() {    
        alert("handler hit");
    });
});
```

Why is the my alert not being hit

Comment: Does $(document).ready fire? What is the result of running $(".bt-cbox") on Firebug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".bt-cbox").live("click",function() {
        alert("handler hit");
    });
});
```

See [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)

Comment: live() is currently depricated.